# When are tags looking like meta-tags not meta-tags?

Tags: discussion, support, meta-tags

From [The Death of Meta Tags - Stack Overflow Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) (emphasis mine):

> How can you tell you’re using a meta-tag? It’s easier than you might think.
>
> - If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s ***probably*** a meta-tag
> - If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it’s ***probably*** a meta-tag

So is it possible to have a tag that can't work as the only tag on a question, but is yet is not a meta-tag? And is it possible to have a tag that commonly means different things to different people, but is yet not a meta-tag? If yes, then you give some examples for this?

Answer (score 2):

> So is it possible to have a tag that can't work as the only tag on a question, but yet not a meta-tag?

Perhaps [[performance]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/performance) on Stack Overflow? Without a proper technology-specific tag like [javascript] or [python], a question won't get much attention because of the personalized homepages. Yet it's often a defining characteristic within a question, so it warrants a separate tag.

Another case is sites which have an unwritten policy that (almost all) questions must be tagged with a tag from a certain collection (e.g. [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com) and [Board & Card Games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/) with a tag specific to the game, [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/) and to a lesser extent [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/) with a country/region-specific tag). A question tagged with just [[rules]](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules) on Sports is probably the result of [tag pruning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag-pruning).

> Is it possible to have a tag that commonly means different things to different people, but yet not a meta-tag?

Yes. [Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag-disambiguation) are (currently) 344 of such examples, where the Stack Overflow community spotted such a tag but decided to disambiguate them. It happens on other sites as well; here on Meta Stack Exchange it usually happens as part of a [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request).

Answer (score 2):

You're asking two separate but related questions, lets unpack it:

> 1. A tag that:
>
>    1.1. can't work as the only tag on a question
>
>    1.2. but is yet not a meta-tag?

In the context of programming these are actually very common, the simplest example are tags that:

- require a parent or language tag. (Check the wikis that say: *"Must/Please/Should include a  language tag"*)
- because, they refer to a programmatic construct or type, e.g [[tag:enum] wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/enums/info) , [[tag:closures] wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/closures/info) that is off-topic without implementation specific details. (Definition of on-topic on Stack Overflow is [*"a specific programming problem"*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic))

> 2. A tag that:
>
>    2.1. commonly means different things to different people
>
>    2.2. but is yet not a meta-tag?

The first example can again apply, if you check the bottom of the [[tag:enum] wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/enums/info) you'll see the keyword expresses different concepts depending on the language.

However, it's the combination of the secondary tag with the language/parent tag that gives an exact, accurate and unambiguous meaning to the search results that allows to filter mere textual occurrences from posts that are specifically about the concept/construct.

**P.S:** A more complex example could be the [[tag:documentation] wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/documentation/info) with its current state reflecting an incomplete tag burnination (likely due to the complexity of completing it), see [It is safe to burn all of our [documentation]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359933).